# Ruby and low-level character encoding

Tags: ruby, encoding, character-encoding

I'm trying to make a little utility where you put binary data in and specify an encoding, and it decodes it into a string for you. But actually, decoding it into a string isn't enough. I want the result to be marked up to show you exactly *which bytes* decoded to *which characters*.

[image]

I'm working in Ruby (maybe I shouldn't be.) It looks like converting a binary encoded string to Unicode and back is very easy, but getting deeper information than that seems difficult if not impossible.

Actually, for *stateless* encodings, the task is possible using the built-in utilities. You feed in progressively longer binary chunks until a character pops out. Then you say that character came from whatever chunks you pumped in and repeat the process. Eventually you get to the end of the string with a list of code points and the bytes which were read to make each one. It isn't an efficient solution but it works without writing too much code.

For *stateful* encodings, it's a bit harder. You often get some bytes worth of code indicating to switch states until told otherwise. These bytes don't correspond to a character and I want them to be represented differently in the output. I can't seem to find a library which does this.

The approach I started to take was to implement the stateful encodings from scratch in Ruby. This way, I get the results I want, but it's a lot of work.

But between the state change markers, stateful encodings are essentially built up from multiple stateless encodings (strictly speaking, it isn't always *between*, sometimes the state change only covers the next character you read.) These encodings, however, are often not bundled with Ruby. For instance, JIS X 0208-1983 is not bundled with Ruby as an encoding, even though it is a part of ISO-2022-JP, which *is* bundled with Ruby.

I found that the ICU project has a large collection of data files for this (albeit with a big disclaimer not to trust any of the data.) I wrote a parser for one of the formats and built up the tables in memory and managed to implement a decoder for JIS X 0208-1983. Now that I have that, I can attempt to code up ISO-2022-JP and try to get things to work together.

But...

Wait... Implementing charset decoding from scratch... and in an interpreted language? That doesn't sound like a good idea at all.

**So I ask:** Is there some existing way to extract this sort of "explanatory" information for a relatively complete set of charsets? Ideally I wanted my collection of charsets to be insanely complete, but maybe if I can skip some effort to cover most of what people will actually have on hand to feed into this thing, I can rest a bit and worry about the rest later.